# Customize structure JSON from string to Array in Codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Iam newer in Codeigniter, I try to create API using it and pars JSON like bellow

[image]

I follow the tutorial but not create JSON structure like that, this is my snippet code

```
function getnew($id="", $limit="", $ofset="", $idp="") {
    if($id=='1') {
        $data = $this->NewsModel->ucweb_row("1", $limit, $ofset);
        $count = $this->NewsModel->news_count();
    }
    else {
        $data = $this->NewsModel->ucweb_row("6", $limit, $ofset, $id);
        $count = $this->NewsModel->news_count_category($id);
    }        

    if($idp != '') {
        $data = $this->NewsModel->setIsLikeIsFav($data, $idp);
    }

    $page = ceil($count/$limit);

    return $this->response([
        'code' => '200',
        'data' => ['size'=>$limit, 
            'row'=>$data
            ],

        ],
    REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
```

this is the result what I get
[image]

how to create result with JSON structure like first pic, sorry for my english

Comment: I am not sure I understand 100%, but this seems to have to do solely with the structure of the JSON, right? This is NOT about codeigniter. So is your question is: How do I format the data so it looks like your first picture?

Comment: images displayed correctly